# Why saving the char '�' to a file saves it as '?'?

Tags: java, save, filewriter

I learned about `Huffman Coding` and tried to apply. So I made a very basic text reader that can only open and save files. And wrote a decorator that can be used to compress the text before saving (which uses `Huffman Coding`).

There was a bug that I couldn't find and after alot of debugging I figured out that when I compress the text, as a result the character `�` may be in the compressed text. For example, the text `',-.:BCINSabcdefghiklmnoprstuvwy` gets compressed to `앐낧淧翵�ဌ䤺큕㈀`.

I figured out that the bug lies in the saving function. When I save the compressed text, it changes every occurence of `�` to `?`. For example, when saving `앐낧淧翵�ဌ䤺큕㈀`, I get `앐낧淧翵?ဌ䤺큕㈀`.

When I try to read the saved file to decompress it, I get a different string so the decompression fails.

What makes it more difficult is that the saving function alone works fine, but it doesn't work when using it in my code. the function looks like this:

```
public void save() throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(this.filename);
    fileWriter.write(this.text);
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

It's confusing that `this.text` at the moment of saving is `앐낧淧翵�ဌ䤺큕㈀` yet it saves it as `앐낧淧翵?ဌ䤺큕㈀`.

As I said before, the function works fine when alone, but doesn't work in my code. I couldn't do any thing more that removing as much as possible from my code and and putting it here. Anyways, a breakpoint can be put at the function `FileEditor::save` and you'll find that `this.text` at the moment of saving is `앐낧淧翵�ဌ䤺큕㈀` and the content of the file is `앐낧淧翵?ဌ䤺큕㈀`.

Code:

`FileEditor` is right below `Main`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import static pack.BitsManipulator.CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String text = " ',-.:BCINSabcdefghiklmnoprstuvwy";

        FileEditor fileEditor2 = new FileEditor("file.txt");
        HuffmanDecorator compressor = new HuffmanDecorator(fileEditor2);
        compressor.setText(text);
        System.out.println(compressor.getText());
        compressor.save();

    }
}

class FileEditor implements BasicFileEditor {
    private String filename;
    private String text;

    public FileEditor(String filename) throws IOException {

        this.filename = filename;
        File file = new File(filename);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        if (!file.createNewFile()) {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

            int ch;
            while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1)
                builder.append((char) ch);
        }

        this.text = builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void save() throws IOException {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(this.filename);
        fileWriter.write(this.text);
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}

interface BasicFileEditor {

    String getText();

    void setText(String text);
    void save() throws IOException;

}

abstract class FileEditorDecorator implements BasicFileEditor {
    FileEditor fileEditor;

    public FileEditorDecorator(FileEditor fileEditor) {
        this.fileEditor = fileEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return fileEditor.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        fileEditor.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void save() throws IOException {
        String oldText = getText();
        setText(getModifiedText());
        fileEditor.save();
        setText(oldText);
    }

    protected abstract String getModifiedText();
}

class HuffmanDecorator extends FileEditorDecorator {

    public HuffmanDecorator(FileEditor fileEditor) {
        super(fileEditor);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getModifiedText() {
        HuffmanCodingCompressor compressor = new HuffmanCodingCompressor(getText());
        return compressor.getCompressedText();
    }
}

class HuffmanCodingCompressor {
    String text;

    public HuffmanCodingCompressor(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getCompressedText() {
        EncodingBuilder builder = new EncodingBuilder(text);

        return builder.getCompressedText();
    }
}

class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public int value;
    public Character character;

    public Node(Node left, Node right, int value) {
        this(left, right, value, null);
    }

    public Node(Node left, Node right, int value, Character character) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.character = character;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        return this.value - o.value;
    }

    public boolean isLeafNode() {
        return left == null && right == null;
    }

    Node getLeft() {
        if (left == null)
            left = new Node(null, null, 0);
        return left;
    }

    Node getRight() {
        if (right == null)
            right = new Node(null, null, 0);
        return right;
    }
}

class EncodingBuilder {

    private String text;
    private Node encodingTree;
    private TreeMap<Character, String> encodingTable;

    public EncodingBuilder(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        buildEncodingTree();
        buildEncodingTableFromTree(encodingTree);
    }

    private void buildEncodingTableFromTree(Node encodingTree) {
        encodingTable = new TreeMap<>();
        buildEncodingTableFromTreeHelper(encodingTree, new StringBuilder());
    }


    public void buildEncodingTableFromTreeHelper(Node root, StringBuilder key) {
        if (root == null)
            return;

        if (root.isLeafNode()) {
            encodingTable.put(root.character, key.toString());
        } else {
            key.append('0');
            buildEncodingTableFromTreeHelper(root.left, key);
            key.deleteCharAt(key.length() - 1);

            key.append('1');
            buildEncodingTableFromTreeHelper(root.right, key);
            key.deleteCharAt(key.length() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void buildEncodingTree() {

        TreeMap<Character, Integer> freqArray = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            // improve here.
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (freqArray.containsKey(c)) {
                Integer freq = freqArray.get(c) + 1;
                freqArray.put(c, freq);
            } else {
                freqArray.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();

        for (Character c : freqArray.keySet())
            queue.add(new Node(null, null, freqArray.get(c), c));

        if (queue.size() == 1)
            queue.add(new Node(null, null, 0, '\0'));

        while (queue.size() > 1) {
            Node n1 = queue.poll();
            Node n2 = queue.poll();

            queue.add(new Node(n1, n2, n1.value + n2.value));
        }

        encodingTree = queue.poll();
    }

    public String getCompressedTextInBits() {
        StringBuilder bits = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
            bits.append(encodingTable.get(text.charAt(i)));

        return bits.toString();
    }

    public String getCompressedText() {
        String compressedInBits = getCompressedTextInBits();
        int remainder = compressedInBits.length() % CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS;
        int paddingNeededToBeDivisibleByCharSize = CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS - remainder;
        String compressed = BitsManipulator.convertBitsToText(compressedInBits + "0".repeat(paddingNeededToBeDivisibleByCharSize));
        return compressed;
    }
}

class BitsManipulator {

    public static final int CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS = 16;

    public static int bitsInStringToInt(String bits) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++) {
            result *= 2;
            result += bits.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String convertBitsToText(String bits) {
        if (bits.length() % CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS != 0)
            throw new NumberOfBitsNotDivisibleBySizeOfCharException();

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i += CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS)
            result.append(asciiInBitsToChar(bits.substring(i, i + CHAR_SIZE_IN_BITS)));

        return result.toString();
    }

    public static char asciiInBitsToChar(String bits) {
        return (char) bitsInStringToInt(bits);
    }

    public static class NumberOfBitsNotDivisibleBySizeOfCharException extends RuntimeException {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

� is the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD. If you encode that in a non-unicode encoding, it will get converted to a regular question mark, as non-unicode encodings can't encode all unicode characters, and this provides a "safety" (i.e. convert everything to question marks that we can't encode).

You seem to be confused about the difference between binary data and text data, leading you to look at compressed data as if it were Korean text instead of binary data. You need to store (and observe) the data as **bytes**, not chars or Strings.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But why doesn't it encode it in a non-unicode encoding in this code? If I just copy paste that code into a new project it encodes it normally.

Comment: @StackExchange123 It does encode it in a non-unicode encoding. It encodes it as a question mark, which presumably can be found from most charsets. If you're storing it in UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 or something other unicode compatible, it will stay as U+FFFD and will be displayed as the authentic � such as in the browser here. But again, that's not very relevant. You're not storing text, you are (or should be) storing binary data.

Comment: Sorry I meant "why does it encode it in a non-unicode encoding?". Why does this happen only in this code? As I said, if I copy-paste the saving function into a new project it works fine. I can also see with the help of the debbuger that the value is correct right before the function ``save`` is called. So why saving a correct value in my code specificly saves it in a non-unicode incoding? The function ``save`` works fine when calling it directly through ``FileEditor``. But when called through ``HuffmanDecorator`` it doesn't encode it in unicode.

Comment: and yeah sure you're right I should store it as a binary file, but in this example, this is just a simple decorator. It can't change the way the saving is done. It just modifies the value after opening and before saving.

Comment: @StackExchange123 probably because you're using `FileWriter` (which should never be used!) which just uses the platform default encoding, so you don't even know what encoding is being used to write your non-text data.

Comment: What should be used instead?

Comment: @StackExchange123 something that allows specifying the encoding, such as an `OutputStreamWriter`. But of course in case of binary data, a direct `FileOutputStream` is used.